# Excel Secondary Axis being Stupid with Stacked Bar Charts

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I hope you can help with this as it is the first time google has no result for an error I thought it was common.
[image: chart error]

I am following the instructions for a bullet chart, but instead of a column, I would like a bar. However, when I try to change the type of chart to a stacked line with markers as per instructions when I have bars, the error above appears and it doesn't let me change. It works ok for columns, but I need it horizontally. I know it is possible, as they are everywhere, so why am I getting this error and how to solve it? Your help is greatly appreciated.

[image: instructions]

Alternatively, if you have a horizontal bullet chart template that allows at least 3 comparative measures, like this (but with 3), it would help. But I'm interested in understanding why this notice is happening to resolve it.
[image: bullet chart]

Comment: Can you perhaps provide instructions as to how to reproduce this error?

Comment: Perhaps the easiest way is to try this tutorial, but instead of columns, use stacked bars. https://www.automateexcel.com/charts/bullet-template/

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want the chart to look like?

Comment: Hi @cybernetic.nomad - I did. It is like the last one in the post :)

Comment: I don't know what tutorial you're using, but a stacked line chart series is uncalled for in any event. I have a tutorial that shows how to build vertical and horizontal bullet charts: [Bullet Charts in Excel](https://peltiertech.com/bullet-charts-in-excel/).